# Is Flex Label baselineshift supported on mobiles?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.5

I need to create subscript text for mobile. I read at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html that label's baselineShift property is not supported on the mobile theme. So I created a plain mobile project using the default mobile theme with a couple of test labels and in the FB 4.5 emulator the baselineshift worked fine.

Why then do they say that it's not supported? Is there anything to stop me going ahead and using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like here is anything to prevent you from using it.  When something like this isn't "supported" it generally means that Adobe is afraid of performance issues that may result in using this.